# Multiple SI units causes "Use of \@@array doesn't match its definition"

Tags: tables, siunitx

When I include 2 `\SI` units in the right column, latex gives me the error `Use of \@@array doesn't match its definition`. Why is this and how can I fix it?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{|l|l|}
    \hline
    left & right \\ \hline
    left & 1, \SI{1e-1}, ..., \SI{1e-5} \\
    \hline
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`\SI` takes two arguments, value and unit. If you just want to format a number, use `\num{...}`. `\SI{A}{B}` can (more or less) be seen as `\num{A}\si{B}`

Comment: ... but please don't use `\num{A}\si{B}` as this does not have the correct spacing between number and unit.